# Add multiple nodes at the same time?

Tags: nodes

I've got a requirement to allow Users the ability to create multiple nodes within a single experience.

All this content the Users are adding share much of the same data, so the idea is to give them a more convenient way to add multiple nodes without all the Save and Add Content clicking.

They don't necessarily need to be able to edit the nodes in the same single experience.

Any modules, and/or case studies you recommend?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [Multi Node Add](https://www.drupal.org/project/multi_node_add) will cover what you require :

> This module provides a new interface for creating nodes where the users are able to select the fields what they want to use for creating the nodes.
>   **It is designed to create multiple nodes in one round,** it's possible to add more node input rows on-the-fly.

See if it does it for you. But also beware that it's a beta release.